# Git diff/merge changes done in same branch (master)

Tags: git, merge, diff

I had been working on a project solely. For keeping track of my changes I used git on that project. The project was completed months back. A month back client wanted some features to be upgraded so I downloaded the project and started to work on the new features, within that time period some serious issue came up to the live server so I had to make some changes over there too.

Now, my question is how do I merge live server changes to my development server new features.

Thanks.

Comment: have you made any separate branch to perform these changes ?

Comment: if you didn't made any separate branch then you can deploy the master branch to you live server but it's always better to use jenkins or some other test setup which is clone of live to test the changes.

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal No I haven't. I have been working in the master branch from the beginning because I was using git just to keep track of my changes.

Comment: then you can commit your changes , push it to the git, merge it to the currently deployed branch and after that make a pull request at live server and restart your service if you are not using merge then you need to replace that step with checkout at live server.

Comment: Did you use git on your production server, did you keep track of those changes?

Comment: Yes @LasseV.Karlsen, I uploaded complete source code including git related files (.git folder) to the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is a common one, and one which is encountered on a daily basis by most users of Git in an enterprise software team environment.  You can try the following steps:

- commit your current local work
- do a `git pull origin branch_name` to bring in the changes from the live server
- resolve any merge conflicts which might have occurred
- then do a `git push origin branch_name` to bring your local changes into the live server

As some of the comments mention, it may not be good design to be working directly with your live server in this fashion.  More typically, you would be working with feature branches, which can be closely reviewed, and then deployed/merged to the live server.

Comment: But for that I would need to commit my changes in live server as well, right? Of which I don't have SSH access but have cpanel access to download the entire source code.

Comment: If you don't have push rights on the server's `master` branch, then there really isn't _anything_ you'll be able to do on the live server.  If so, then you'll need to resolve this first.  Maybe you could create a separate branch and then have an admin merge it into `master`.

Comment: Umm, well I think I can get the SSH access if I request it to the hosting provider. But I haven't configured anything in the beginning thinking of this scenario. All I did was `git init` and staged & committed my changes and uploaded the entire files to live server via FTP. Could you provide me some reference on that.